# Postfix for cross references of enum lists

Tags: cross-referencing, enumerate

I have a question to manipulate cross references to enumeration lists.
To change the appearance of the list, I know the commands `\theenumi` to choose the type (roman, arabic, alph...), `\labelenumi` for the label in the list and `\p@enumi` as prefix for a cross reference. But is there also a macro for the postfix?

As an example I would like to realize the following:

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \label{item 1} Item
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \label{subitem 1} Subitem
        \item Second Subitem
    \end{enumerate}
    \item Another item
\end{enumerate}
```

where a reference `\ref{item1}` gives `(i)` and `\ref{subitem 1}` gives `(ia)`.
I can define

```
\renewcommand*{\theenumi}{\roman{enumi}}
\renewcommand*{\theenumii}{\alph{enumii}}
\renewcommand*{\labelenumi}{(\theenumi)}
\renewcommand*{\labelenumii}{(\theenumii)}
```

which gives me `(i)` and `(a)` in the list itself. For the cross references I could try something like

```
\renewcommand*{\p@enumi}{(}
\renewcommand*{\p@enumii}{\p@enumi\theenumi}
```

which gives me the first bracket, resulting in `(i` and `(ia`. But how to close the bracket?

More academically than for real use I would like to know also a solution for three or four nested lists (although it would look ugly).

I suppose there are easy solution using additional packages. But my question is really about a possible macro for a postfix, which somehow I would expect to exist. Therefore an additional question: How can I (as newbie) find a list of defined macros?

Comment: Look at section 51.2 of source2e.pdf (type `texdoc source2e` at the terminal, then go to section 51.2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your elementary example it suffices to capture what follows the `p`refix using TeX's parameter text setup:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\theenumi}{\roman{enumi}}
\renewcommand*{\theenumii}{\alph{enumii}}
\renewcommand*{\labelenumi}{(\theenumi)}
\renewcommand*{\labelenumii}{(\theenumii)}

\def\p@enumi\csname #1\endcsname{(\theenumi)}% First level
\def\p@enumii\csname #1\endcsname{(\theenumi\theenumii)}% Second level
% \def\p@enumiii\csname #1\endcsname{(\theenumi\theenumii\theenumiii)}% Third level
%...
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{First}\label{section1}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item \label{item1} Item
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item \label{subitem1} Subitem
    \item Second Subitem
  \end{enumerate}
  \item Another item~\ref{subitem1}
\end{enumerate}

Those are references to items:~\ref{item1} and~\ref{subitem1}, but this reference here~\ref{section1} does not have parentheses. 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is in fact the `\label` command that writes a `\newlabel{foo}{\@currentlabel}{\thepage}` to the `.aux` file. Since `\@currentlabel` is already the expanded version of `\p@...` etc. it's too early to use something like `(\p@...)`.

In my point of view the `(...)` pair has to be written to the `.aux` file by the `\@currentlabel{...}` and can't be added to `\p@....` itself, due to `\protected@edef` and the involved expansion of the `\@p...` chain.

I've applied this strategy by adding some code after the start-up of `enumerate`, redefining `\@currentlabel` only slightly to have this `(...)` pair as wrapper around `\p@...\the...`.

A redefinition of `\refstepcounter` to add the `(...)` is not sufficient -- this would be applied to any counter being refstepped. The following code checks first if the current environment is `enumerate` and applies the relevant setting then. (It might fail however for other counters that are `\refstepped` with enumerate, but not within a group.

Since all is in an (environment) group, the redefinition of `\refstepcounter` does not leak outside.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\renewcommand*{\theenumi}{\roman{enumi}}
\renewcommand*{\theenumii}{\alph{enumii}}
\renewcommand*{\labelenumi}{(\theenumi)}
\renewcommand*{\labelenumii}{(\theenumii)}



\newcommand{\@@labelprefix}{%
(%
}

\newcommand{\@@labelpostfix}{%
  )%
}


\let\@@latex@@refstepcounter\refstepcounter

\def\is@@enumerate{enumerate}

\def\refstepcounter#1{%
  \ifx\@currenvir\is@@enumerate
  \stepcounter{#1}%
  \protected@edef\@currentlabel{\@@labelprefix\csname p@#1\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname\@@labelpostfix}
  \else
  \@@latex@@refstepcounter{#1}%
  \fi
}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{First}\label{section1}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \label{item1} Item
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \label{subitem1} Subitem
        \item Second Subitem
          \begin{figure}
            \caption{foo}\label{firstfoo}
            \end{figure}

    \end{enumerate}
    \item Another item \ref{subitem1}
\end{enumerate}


Those are references to items: \ref{item1} and \ref{subitem1}, but this reference here \ref{section1} does not have parentheses. 

A reference for \ref{firstfoo}

\end{document}
```

**It would be easier with `enumitem` package ;-)**

[image]